# why leading 0 is removed from nvarchar in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my `Staff` table, there is a `staffID` column which is `nvarchar(100)`.

One of the user id is `08888`. So when I select like that

```
SELECT StaffID From Staff
```

it removes the leading 0 and returns only `8888`.

Why is the leading 0 removed although it is a `nvarchar(100)`?

I am using SQL Server.

Thanks !!

Comment: What tool are you using to execute the SQL and display the result?

Comment: If it is stored as a string, then the database is not removing the leading zero.  How are you looking at the data?

Comment: Are you using some sort of 'smart' gui which is evaluating the result and presenting it as a number instead? Try cast it as nvarchar(100) to tell your editor that it doesn't know better and you want it as a string.

Comment: Agree with @GordonLinoff. Either your are _not_ storing it as a string, or the way you are viewing it has converted it to a number first.

Comment: I would assume that you cast nvarchar to an integer in your program and thats why you may be seeing that the leading zero is gone.

Comment: I use management studio for the query.
I don't do any casting. I just do normal statement as I mention in my question. But leading zero (0) is missing in the result.

Comment: It could be removed at the time of INSERT. How do you know that the zero is there?

Comment: My guess is that the string is being inadvertently converted to a number either on the way into the database, or possibly even on the way from the database.

Comment: @kevin From where (which front end application) you are soring the staffid

Comment: I have a (somewhat) similar experience. A developer set up an SSIS package to load a plaintext file. SSIS sampled the first 200 rows of the txt file, found that they were all convertible to integer so it used `int` as data type, then convert it again into `varchar` at the destination table. Took us a while to find out why the leading `0`s were missing.

Comment: @kevin Can you please share the code which inserts records to thsi table from your application?

Comment: I have used the API developed by another team. So I don't have the source code for it. I save it as a string in my C# codes and it's nvarchar(100) in sql. I asked the API team to check whether other faced the same issue before and they said "no one".